# Good java library for Windows application automation

Tags: java, windows, automation

I am looking for a best way to trigger windows application automation from Java application. So far I have been using Groovy and Scriptom library to access COM native interface. It is rather straight forward approach, but does not scale well (writing configuration for each of application, reading brilliant COM documentations, testing, testing etc.)

I am looking now for better way to automate windows application from Java application. Is there any java library that could help me? Maybe I should use a non-java framework, e.g., [autoit](http://autoitscript.com), and call it from Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [JACOB (Java-COM Bridge) project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/).

It's a Java library that uses JNI to make native calls into the COM and Win32 libraries.

More info (and examples) [here](http://danadler.com/jacob/) and [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33305).

Comment: Scriptom is a groovy wrapping library around JACOB.

Comment: I didn't know. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

Try JWinAuto. JWinAuto is a simple wrapper around AutoIt to allow java applications to automate Win32 GUIs.

http://jwinauto.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

There's also a commercial product from http://www.nevaobject.com/ the provides this functionality.  I've used older versions without any problems...other than having to understand the challenges around COM.

Comment: This link seems dead.

Comment: I think Neva is no longer.  I did a variety of searches and couldn't find any record of acquisition or transference of IP.