# Any java based open source tool like AutoIT?

Tags: java

Any java based open source tool like AutoIT to simulate windows functions

Comment: java is far too detached from the windows api for what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [java-and-macros-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092176/java-and-macros-project), we can assume that not many projects will do that in Java.

the closest thing to consider as an answer to your question (even though I admit not 100%) are the following posts:

[autoit-for-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097528/autoit-for-java)

and

[good-java-library-for-windows-application-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776427/good-java-library-for-windows-application-automation)

Comment: i tried to open a notepad using following fuction of JWinAuto but it does not seem to be working   lib.AU3_WinActivate("Untitled - Notepad", "");
it is returning void so i can't check for any type of  return type

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) and [Maveryx](http://www.maveryx.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Sikulix](http://sikulix.com) is adding OCR-based automation and a GUI to [Robot.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) features.
See on [github](https://github.com/RaiMan)